# Objective C: save array of items (NSCoder)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoder

I am working on challenges from iOS Big Nerd Ranch book of 12th chapter and there is a problem of saving an array of items to the disk. I have `BNRDrawView UIView` that has an array `finishedLines` that holds items `BNRLine` defined by me. I want to use `NSCoder` for the purpose. So, I implemented inside `BNRDrawView` two methods:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:_finishedLines forKey:finishedLinesKey];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];

if (self) {
    _finishedLines = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:finishedLinesKey];
}
    return self;
}
```

and trying to save `finishedLines` array whenever it is changed like this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.finishedLines
                            toFile:self.finishedLinesPath];
```

Loading I am trying to do inside `initWithFrame` BNRDrawView method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)r
{
...
self.finishedLinesPath = @"/Users/nikitavlasenko/Desktop/XCodeProjects/MyFirstApp/TouchTracker/savedLines/finishedLines";
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       fileExistsAtPath:self.finishedLinesPath];
    if (fileExists) {
        self.finishedLines = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                              unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.finishedLinesPath];
    }
...
```

It gives me the error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BNRLine encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd32510c40'`

From here I have two questions:

1. Do I need to implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` for ALL of the classes - let's suppose that I have a plenty of different ones, defined by me - that are inside my array that I am trying to save?
2. If you look above to my `initWithCoder:` method, you can see that I need to call `[super initWithCoder:decoder]`, but do I also need to call BNRDrawView's initializer method `initWithFrame:` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you need to implement `NSCoder` in all objects that are stored inside the array.
2. No, you don't need to call `initWithFrame` - `initWithCoder` is sufficient.